# prevent duplicate entries before posting data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a dynamic row where end-user can append extra rows if needed. I also have restricted duplicate entries into database by querying the table for existing data before inserting. If user inputs serial number 001 and then submits, and try to submit another serial number 001, the system returns an error. The problem i have now is that if the user inputs serial number 001 on two different rows at the same time, the restriction is bypassed. Is there a way to prevent this php/ajax? or would this fall on js? please site some simple examples. Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var counter = 2;
     $('.add-row').click(function() {
           $(".item_form").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="serialnoa[]" placeholder="serial no.' +
         counter + '"/></td></tr>');
   counter++; });
   $('.del-row').click(function() {
       if($(".item_form tr").length != 2)
         {
            $(".item_form tr:last-child").remove();
            counter--; 
         }
      else
         {
            alert("You cannot delete first row");
         }
          });
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/inventory.css?v=<?=time();?>">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  
<table class="item_form">
<tr>
  <th>serial no.</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="text" placeholder="serial no.1" name="serialnoa[]"></td>
</tr>
</table> 

<table>
<tr>
 <td><a href="#" class="add-row"><div>+ Row</div></td>
 <td><a href="#" class="del-row"><div>- Row</div></td>
         
</tr>
</table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try setting Unique index for that column in your database?

Comment: if i do that it will prevent it yes but if im not mistaken it wont return an error. so end user wont know what happened. theyll probably think that everything went fine without knowing that they made a mistake in inserting the 2nd items serial number.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj thanks for being the only one to suggest anything. I think i found a solution. using count(array_unique($array)) < count($array)

Comment: As  Mohit Bhardwaj suggested you can make a Unique field for taking care on server side and do a js validation on client side to check for duplicate entry

Comment: @user3273700 i will also try both your suggestions after trying out all the possibilites with the solution ive found. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

If serial number is just record counter, then it's better to set its value automatically -  when your page loads take the last serial number from database, and increment serial number from that value as user add new rows.

If serial number is some unique number that user inputs, then you can make one more AJAX call to PHP method that will be checking number uniqueness "on the fly" when user inputs it. And also in order to prevent user from duplicating serial numbers during one input session, create JavaScript code that checks number uniqueness.